# reading python dataframe and one column is represent as string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let say I have df

df

```
bbox

[34,23,2,3]
```

then when I try

```
df['bbox'][0] = '[34,23,2,3]'
```

when I do list

```
list(df['bbox'][0]) = ['[',
 '1',
 '2',
 '1',
 '.',
 '0',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '2',
 '0',
 '4',
 '.',
 '0',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '1',
 '0',
 '8',
 '.',
 '0',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '1',
 '4',
 '7',
 '.',
 '0',
 ']']
```

How should I make it just normal list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast
df['bbox'] = df['bbox'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Hope this is your requirement

[image]

Comment: ValueError: malformed node or string: [121.0, 204.0, 108.0, 147.0]
gives this error

Comment: This must be some other issue. I have tested and it works. Look at the latest edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler version to solve this

```
eval(df['bbox'][0])
```

prints your list which is `[121.0, 204.0, 108.0, 147.0]`

Comment: @slowmonk Did you try this?